# FFMpeg Merge audio and video files

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I need to Merge an audio (.mp3) and video (.mov) file and output an mp4 file using FFMpeg PHP library.

The following works:

```
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe'
]);

/* Open video file */
$video = $ffmpeg->open('sample.mov');

/* Resize video */
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();

/* Take screenshot from video */
$video->frame(\FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
    ->save('screen.jpg');
```

However it's not quite what I need.
The following command line code is exactly what I'm looking for but I can't figure out how to convert it into the same format as the above ($ffmpeg version).

```
exec("ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4");
```

Question: 
Anyone know how to convert the exec into PHP above?

Thanks guys.

Comment: No need for `-strict experimental` unless your ffmpeg is a thousand years old.

Comment: Thanks @llogan I've removed it. Have you used the \FFMpeg\FFMpeg library? How to run this exec command it appears to do nothing when run

Comment: No, sorry. Only familiar with the `ffmpeg` command-line tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with full paths

```
$cmd = 'C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4';
exec($cmd, $output)
```

Looks like its not implemented in PHP-FFMPEG package, you have to do it that way.

https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/346#issuecomment-292701054

Comment: thanks very much, it outputs the file now but actually there is no sound.Tried with .mov and also .mp4. Both are transcoded to mp4 but I'm not hearing any sound with them..

Comment: you have to play with commands, I just helped to run commands. Check ffmped documentation for more combinations.

Comment: try this: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4

Answer (score 0):

There is not an explicit PHP-FFMPEG function, but it is possible to build your custom command.

Here an example to generate an MP4 video merging a PNG image and an MP3 file.

```
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$advancedMedia = $ffmpeg->openAdvanced(['image.png', 'audio.mp3']);
$advancedMedia->map([], new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac', 'libx264'), 'output.mp4')->save();
```

More details [in the "AdvancedMedia" paragraph](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#advancedmedia) of the documentation.